# How to Update Version Pod Packages?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

This what I have now in my Pod file

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'ListHue' do 
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SwipeCellKit'
  pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon.git'
end
```

I want to update to this

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'ListHue' do 
  pod 'RealmSwift'
  pod 'SwipeCellKit','2.5.0'
  pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/ViccAlexander/Chameleon.git'
end
```

What is the command I need to run when I need to update my Pod package ?

`pod update` or `pod install` or both  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pod install` to install new pods in your project and `pod update [PODNAME]` (without the name if you want to update all the pods to the last version) only when you want to update pods to a newer version.

More information in [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html) cocoapods guide.